# Examples of using Azure Service Bus with AMQP 1.0 clients

Tags: amqp, azureservicebus, servicebus

A lot of materials about Service Bus mention that it uses AMQP 1.0. However, examples I have found use libraries that hide away AMQP layer, so it is not obvious how would one use generic AMQP 1.0 client and do things 
[that are listed in this Service Bus example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/)

Being able to use independent AMQP client instead of supplied higher level clients might be important in several scenarios. For instance supplied clients might not be available at some platforms, or generic clients might provide more suitable way of working for particular problem.

[Possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819069/trying-to-communicate-with-azure-service-bus-from-android-device-using-proton-j)

Answer (score 0):

Little bit further from .net example I had linked in question I have found following [example of how to access Service Bus with Proton AMQP 1.0 Python library](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-amqp-python/). It shows how to send and receive messages.

What is lacking in that example, is how to create and manage queues and topics. It appears that this is not possible from AMQP interface, and needs to be done out of the band through either web azure console, or through REST interface.